# #neo4j Initialization error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: neo4j

I have neo4j Desktop on Mac version 1.0.15, but for some reason it keeps showing the error below. I already tried reinstalling many times. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: anything more in the logs ?

Comment: i wouldn't know where to look, i'm just start learning about it but i can't get it run

Comment: download the server install as archive. If you have Java, it will run by running "neo4j start". Spend time on the website, read a dedicated book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We resolved it by deleting the APPDATA directory, i.e. on the mac: `Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop` and restarting the app.

It's a bug that will be fixed in the next version.

Sorry for that.

Comment: This works also for version 1.2.3 which has the same issue.

Comment: I just faced this same issue with version 1.2.3, so obviously the bug is still not fixed.