# Neo4j Desktop Error on Open - "cannot read property "name" of undefined

Tags: neo4j

I have a box running Windows Server 2016 box. I found an answer to this question regarding a MAC here:  [#neo4j Initialization error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998760/neo4j-initialization-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined/49196417#49196417)

This answer does not seem to work in windows as removal of 'AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Desktop' caused the application not to open; however, a background process was started. 
The AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Desktop\log.txt file shows this error:

```
App initialization error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\ecxadmin\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Desktop\Application\graphApps'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you delete that folder, you need to uninstall Neo4j Desktop and then reinstall again for it to work.