# Neo4J - error Win 10 - Initialization error: TypeError: Cannot read property: 'name' of undefined

Tags: neo4j

Error occured after updating 21 to 24.
Deleting AppDate/Neo4j Desktop as suggested here: [Neo4j Desktop Error on Open - "cannot read property "name" of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198296/neo4j-desktop-error-on-open-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined/50153564#50153564) 
doesn´t help.

Reinstall of either 21 or 24 doesn´t help.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

I additionally hat to delete the Folder ".Neo4jDesktop" , found searching my Computer for "neo4j".

Reinstall worked.

Comment: Where is this file typically located?

Comment: It is in `C:\Users\<user-name>\` for me, but might change depending on whether you installed for all users or just yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Mac OS

- Uninstall Neo4jDesktop
- Delete the folder at /Users//Library/Application Support/Neo4jDesktop
- Reinstall Neo4jDesktop