# Neo4j Initialization error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: neo4j-desktop

I'm having the same issue as [#neo4j Initialization error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998760/neo4j-initialization-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined/49196417#49196417) on MacOS High Sierra.

The issue is I can't find the suggested directory to delete **Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop** as per the answer given?

The directory doesn't exist and I have uninstalled and reinstalled but still have the same issue? Please can somebody point me to where the directory is in order to delete as I have searched and can't find it?

I'm due to give a POC and Neo4J is a busted flush at the moment :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the directory at the following path (original suggestion was missing the **~** at the start of the path!

**~/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop**