# Neo4j Desktop doesn't start up anymore after deleting older unused projects

Tags: neo4j, electron, neo4j-desktop

I wanted to free up some space to load my next dataset into Neo4j, but after deleting a few unused, older projects, it just doesn't start up anymore. The error I get happens to be the exact error as reported in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998760/neo4j-initialization-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined), even though my Neo4j desktop version is `1.2.3` (the latest available version)-

```js
Initialization error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

[image: Screen Shot 2019-12-28 at 6 28 23 PM]

I tried restarting Neo4j Desktop several times, and each time, it's the same thing.

I checked the "developer tools" tab, and there is a whole bunch of stuff in the console. I put all of it in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Manish-Giri/9231a6236ed4dc0f4073e68c8765ef75), if it helps.

Here's the relevant portion of the console which has this error message -

[image: Screenshot 2019-12-28 18 43 23]

The problem is that the suggested solution involves deleting this path - `~/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop` and reinstalling Neo4j Desktop. I cannot do a reinstall since my thesis is on Neo4j, and all of my data (~around 400GB) is already on neo4j desktop. It also took me months to load all the datasets.

I also **cannot** delete the `~/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop` folder, because the folder size is ~400GB, approximately the same size as my datasets, so obviously my data is all in that folder.

I would appreciate any help to resolve this error/issue, without having to delete all my data. I have already posted on neo4j's [github](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/12370) and their [community](https://community.neo4j.com/t/neo4j-desktop-initialization-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined/13198), but haven't received any response yet.

Comment: Make sure that your database folder is available. A path verification can be made by looking at https://community.neo4j.com/t/where-is-neo4j-home/6488/2.

For testing verificationm just copy the database folder to any other machine and place the database folder there and direct the installation to the database path. 

If you have database folder available, you can delete and reinstall all the thing as many times as you want.

Comment: I just checked on my windows machine, but contrary to that answer, there is no folder called `neo4jDatabases` in `C:\Program Files\Neo4j Desktop`. Besides, I was working on a mac when Neo4j Desktop stopped working, and I'm pretty sure the path I linked in my post, is the home directory for neo4j installs on macOS. It also is reachable because I checked its size (in both finder and terminal). And lastly, the problem is since the folder size is ~400GB, I can't just transport it to another machine (no external HDD and machine available with that much free space).

Comment: I use Neo4j Community Server for Linux/Mac https://neo4j.com/download-center/#community. My neo4j database location is `~/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db` . I did 10s of times delete this `graph.db` directory, whenever i needed to create a new database or change the machine, i just copy that directory. So, if i need to create a new database, i just keep a keep a copy of `graph.db` if needed, for example, `graph-backup.db` . And to restore the database, i just delete the existing `graph.db` and rename `graph-backup.db` to `graph.db`. 

This is just sharing of my experience, if it works for u.

Comment: Keeping the above comment in context, if you have lost `graph.db`, for example, then i am sorry, i think you have lost your data.

Good luck!

Comment: Can you pls provide the full path to the `graph.db` folder when you’re on your computer next time? I want to figure out what that path might be on my Mac. Also, I don’t know if you use Neo4j desktop, or use neo4j directly via a lang like java or python, but Neo4j desktop allows you to create “projects”, inside which you can create different “graphs”. Each graph in each project is probably stored in a separate folder in the home directory, so I don’t really know how to differentiate between my thesis graphs DBs and the test graphs dbs (which I was originally trying to delete to free up space).

Comment: the path of database would always be somewhere in `/databases/` .  My path is exactly the same as i mentioned and `~` is my home directory in Linux. I didn't use desktop version of neo4j, so i don't have any idea about it.